# SQL Query with two different filters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a page which shows all cars from DB.
I have two filters , both are multiple select filter.
**For example**

> filter 1 - Color

Red , green , blue <-- All these are checkbox ,can be selected multiple

> filter 2 - brand

BMW, Honda , Hyundai <-- All these are checkbox ,can be selected multiple

I have done below query

```
Select * from cars
JOIN term_car_relationships  
ON cars.id = term_cars_relationships.car_id 
 WHERE term_cars_relationships.term_id in (6,2,3) 
GROUP BY cars.id
```

In above query term_id

6 = blue (Color)

2 = green (Color)

3 = BNW (brand)

But with above query I will get all cars which has blue color or green color or BMW brand
But how to change in such a way that I get BMW which is blue or green color.

I have 3 tables which handles these categories.

taxonomy table

```
taxonomy_id | taxonomy_title
1           | Color
2           | Brand
```

term_list

```
term_id  |  term_name  |  taxonomy_id
1        | Blue        | 1
2        | Red         | 1
3        | BMW         | 2
4        | Honda       | 2
```

term_cars_relationships Table

```
 term_id | car_id   
     1      |  1
     1      |  2
     2      |  3
```

Comment: Unless the data set is vast, consider just loading the entire data set into a bit of json and handling the filtering there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct your query with separate joins for each term category, and separate filter conditions for each as well.

```
SELECT cars.*, colorTerms.*, brandTerms.* 
FROM cars
INNER JOIN term_car_relationships AS carColorTerms
   ON cars.id = carColorTerms.car_id
INNER JOIN term_list AS colorTerms 
   ON carColorTerms.term_id = colorTerms.term_id AND colorTerms.taxonomy_id = 1
INNER JOIN term_car_relationships AS carBrandTerms
   ON cars.id = carBrandTerms.car_id
INNER JOIN term_list AS brandTerms 
   ON carBrandTerms.term_id = brandTerms.term_id AND brandTerms.taxonomy_id = 2
WHERE colorTerms.term_id IN (6, 2)
   AND brandTerms.term_id IN (3)
```

Of course, to construct this query, you will need to know the terms' types before the query.

---

Also, using `GROUP BY cars.id` without aggregation is probably a sign of a problem, or just not the right way to get what you want. If you only want the information from the `cars` table, you should just `SELECT DISTINCT cars.*`. Using `GROUP BY` in this manner will end up with results with the data from just one color-brand match for each car.

---

With the complexity the edit to the original question added, another possibility presents itself....

```
SELECT cars.* -- You should really just select the fields you want, and may have to in some configurations (see GROUP BY)
FROM cars AS c
INNER JOIN term_car_relationships AS tcr ON c.car_id = tcr.car_id
INNER JOIN term_list AS tl ON tcr.term_id = tl.term_id
WHERE tcr.term_id IN (6, 2, 3)
GROUP BY cars.car_id -- In some configurations of MySQL, and most other RDBMSes, you must specify every SELECTed non-aggregated field here
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tl.taxonomy_id) 
   = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT taxonomy_id) 
       FROM term_list 
       WHERE term_id IN (6, 2, 3)
     )
```

Note: This final solution does not actually require you to know term taxonomies ahead of time anymore, and does not grow as more taxonomies need supported; so while it is a little less obvious with what it is doing, is probably definitely worth considering.

Comment: Actually type_of_category stores the ID of taxonomy (color or brand) i.e 1 or 2 . So Should I use `ON cars.id = colorTerms.car_id AND colorTerms.type_of_category = '1'` ?  Is it a good practice ?

Comment: I was just going by your description of the table, having an id/int is definitely better. Having the additional category filtering in the join rather than the where is debatable; _conceptually_, the JOIN happens before the WHERE, so including the filtering there can reduce the size of intermediate results, but MySQL is pretty good about applying WHERE conditions early when it can help. I prefer keeping it in the join; it helps to identify what that instance of the table being joined is used for (often an alias cannot be descriptive enough) and minimizes vertical scanning to determine that.

Comment: I am really really sorry for the confusion, I am working on this for very long, my mind is not working currently. Could you please  check my updated question. I have given my table structure. Please check.

Comment: It's become a little more convoluted now, but I've updated the query I provided.

Comment: Yeah you are right , should I change my table structure such that only 2 tables are there for terms so that I will have less JOIN ,such as `term_list` (`term_id , taxonomy_name ,term_name`) values will be like (1,Color,Red and 2,Color,BLue and so on) , second table will be `relationship` (`term_id,movie_id`)

Comment: The table structure you have is fine actually; you'll note I never actually had to join to `taxonomy`, and int values compare and sort faster. If I would change anything it would be to actually have more tables, a different set of tables for each "taxonomy". Numeric traits do not sort or compare well stored as strings, so "cars that get mpg between x and y" could be difficult for your current structure.

Comment: @xteeem See the final note I added at the bottom of the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should join the `term_cars_relationships` table twice:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM cars
    JOIN term_car_relationships c ON cars.id = c.car_id 
    JOIN term_car_relationships b ON cars.id = b.car_id 
    WHERE c.type_of_category = 'color'
    AND b.type_of_category = 'brand'
    AND c.term_id in (6,2)
    AND b.term_id in (3)
    GROUP BY cars.id
```

Note that I used `b.term_id in (3)` instead of `b.term_id = 3` since I assumed you might want to select multiple brands.

Comment: Could you please check my table structure in my updated question.